# Return equivalent of `:` from function for indexing array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large array and a function that returns index lists into the array, i.e.,

```
import numpy

n = 500
a = numpy.random.rand(n)

def get_idx(k):
    # More complicated in reality
    return range(n) if k > 6 else range(k)

data = a[get_idx(29)]
data = a[get_idx(30)]
# ...
```

A typical case is that the range is the entire array, `range(n)`. Unfortunately, `a[range(n)]` scales with `n` while `a[:]` is of course constant-time. It's a pity that one cannot return `:` from `get_idx`.

What can I return from `get_idx` to use as an index for the entire array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NumPy has a helper [`np.s_[]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html#numpy.s_) which can be used to construct `slice` and `Ellipsis` objects:

```
def get_idx(k):
    return np.s_[:] if k > 6 else np.s_[:k]

    # or even np.s_[:None if k > 6 else k]
```

In general, `a[np.s_[ <stuff> ]]` is exactly the same as `a[ <stuff> ]`.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)

```
def get_x():
    return slice(2)

a=list(range(100))
a[get_x()]
```

will return `[0, 1]`

### UPDATE

And for your need `get_x` function should be

```
def get_x(k, n):
    return slice(n if k > 6 else k)
```

#### Update

as @Eric correctly noted it's better to pass `None` instead of `n`.
So function would be:

```
def get_x(k):
    return slice(None if k > 6 else k)
```

Comment: `None` would be better than passing `n` here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Ellipsis` (translates to '...')

```
np.identity(2)[Ellipsis]
# array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
```

Edit:

I feel I should mention one caveat: If you are sure this will only be used on 1d arrays, it's a perfectly fine and simple solution. However, in a public interface I wouldn't recommend it because it doesn't generalise correctly if a user uses the output of `getidx` for indexing a multi dimensional array.

For example `A[getidx(k), ...]` won't be safe anymore and the semantics of `A[getidx(k), someslice]` will be inconsistent if `A` has three or more dims.

That said, `slice(None)` isn't perfect in this respect either, for exammple `A[getidx(k), getidx(k)]` will behave inconsistently.

`arange(n)` looks like it's always giving the correct behaviour, but of course it's wasteful in most cases.