# numpy advanced indexing: transparently optimising ranges?

Tags: python, numpy

This is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392260/return-equivalent-of-from-function-for-indexing-array) post.

Consider a function `f` that returns a 1d `np.ndarray` `idx` of indices which the user will typically use to index other arrays. Assume further that a frequent outcome is for `f` to return the full range of legal indices. In the linked post it is suggested this be special-cased by `f` returning `slice(None)` instead of `np.arange(maxind)`.

Since advanced indexing comes at a cost

```
>>> a = np.arange(1_000_000)
>>> direct = lambda: np.sum(a[:])
>>> indirect = lambda: np.sum(a[a])
>>> timeit(direct, number=100)
0.07656216900795698
>>> timeit(indirect, number=100)
0.2885982050211169
```

this looks like a reasonable optimisation at first sight.

Unfortunately, it is not "correct". Imagine, for example, the user wants to create a one-hot representation of `idx`. One straightforward way of going about this is

```
result = np.zeros((k, maxind), dtype=int)
result[np.arange(k), idx] = 1
```

This breaks if `np.arange(maxind)` is substituted by `slice(None)` (It will fill the whole of `result` with ones).

So my question is: Can one have one's cake and eat it here, i.e.:

**Is there anything `f` could return that faithfully mimics the semantics of `np.arange(maxind)` while avoiding advanced indexing where possible?**

Since I'm almost resigned to the answer being no:

**What's the next best thing?**

Maybe return an "enhanced `np.s_`", i.e. an object with an engineered `__getitem__`?

```
class smart_idx:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        idx = idx if isinstance(idx, tuple) else (idx,)
        if idx:
            count = idx.count('X')
            need_adv = count > 1
            if count == 1:
                for i in idx:
                    if not isinstance(i, slice) and i != Ellipsis:
                        need_adv = True
                        break
            repl = np.arange(self.n) if need_adv else slice(None)
            return tuple(repl if i == 'X' else i for i in idx)
        return slice(None)
```

The user would have to use it like

```
data[idx[3, 4:9, 'X', [1,3,2,6]]]
data[idx['X', ..., :4:-1]]
data[idx[]]
```

and `__getitem__`, detecting the advanced index would decide to replace 'X' with `np.arange(4)` in the first and with `slice(None)` in the other two examples.

But that's rather clunky, not to mention that the overhead added might eat up whatever speed we gained.

**Are there simpler strategies?**

Comment: If `idx` is a list/array you are going to get advanced indexing, regardless of whether you use a slice or arange for the to the other index.  In the `[arange...,idx]` indexing it is picking one item from each row.  Indexing on a flattened array is faster, but counterbalanced by the cost of computing the flat index.

Comment: @hpaulj "If idx is a list/array you are going to get advanced indexing, regardless". That is why we are trying to substitute `idx` with `slice(None)` in special cases where that makes sense (basically `idx==np.arange(maxind)` + no other advanced indices around).

Comment: What @hpaulj was trying to say, is that regardless of what `idx` is, when you do indexing for arbitrary positions in >1D (2D in your example), e.g. `[something..., idx]` it is advanced indexing regardless of what `idx` could possibly be, unless both `something` and `idx` are `slice` objects, but that case would never mimic your desired behaviour.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Yes, I know that. Still, no advanced indexing in any axis is a common enough use-case, so it would be nice if one could optimise that in a more or less transparent way.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [104]: x=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
```

These look the same, though one is a copy, the other a view:

```
In [107]: x[np.arange(0,4,2),:]
Out[107]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [108]: x[0:4:2,:]
Out[108]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

But if the 2nd index is an array, the `arange` and `slice` aren't substitutes.

```
In [109]: idx=np.array([0,2])
In [110]: x[np.arange(0,4,2),idx]
Out[110]: array([0, 8])
In [111]: x[0:4:2,idx]
Out[111]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8]])
```

To match the sliced version I have to add a dimension to the `arange`.

```
In [113]: x[np.ix_(np.arange(0,4,2),idx)]
Out[113]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8]])
In [114]: x[np.arange(0,4,2)[:,None],idx]
Out[114]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8]])
```

I'm not aware of a slice expression that produces `Out[110]`.

So apart from replacing an `arange` with a `slice`, we need to pay attention as to how the advanced indexing arrays broadcast against each other, and what broadcasting is implied by slicing.

With 3 or more dimensions, mixing slices and advanced indexing gets even more complicated, as described in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing