# Alternative to `:` that selects everything

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that in

```
np.arange(3)[:]
```

the `:` implies that I want all elements from the particular dimension. Now, I need to be flexible in terms of which elements I want. I have a function similar to:

```
def pickSomething(index):
    return np.arange(3)[index]
```

where `index` can be 0, 1 or 2. However, I would also like to be able to return the whole array without transforming it. `pickSomething(:)` naturally is invalid syntax. If I do `pickSomething(None)`, I create an additional dimension I don't want to.

**tl;dr**: Is there an alternative to `:` that I can pass along in  a function like `pickSomething(index)`, that will yield me the unchanged `np.arange(3)` array?

Comment: See if this helps - [`Return equivalent of `:` from function for indexing array`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42392260/3293881).

Comment: @Divakar it does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `Ellipsis` object.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def pickSomething(index):
...     return np.arange(3)[index]
>>> pickSomething(Ellipsis)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

In Python 3 `...` is a shorthand for `Ellipsis`.